# how to use getBaseContext() in class which is not extends Activity

Tags: android, module, titanium

I am creating a module that extends from another class but i need to use getBaseContext(). how can I use it in my own module?
If I have to run the activity then how to do that if not how to solve the problem
thanks

```
public class TelcoModule extends KrollModule
{
...

        // Methods
    @Kroll.method
    public String GetTelco()
    {
           TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
           String operatorName = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
           return operatorName ;
          }
}
```

Comment: just pass the context in your constructor for the class

Comment: `Context mContext;public TelcoModule(Context context)
{mContext =context;// use mContext..}`. pass like `new TelcoModule(ActivityName.this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `GetTelco` to include a context param. Then call it using your available context from anywhere

```
public String GetTelco(final Context context)
{
       TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       String operatorName = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
}
```

Example of calling it:

```
someView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String telcoName = myTelcoInstance.GetTelco(v.getContext())
    }
});
```

Comment: Whit the help of your comment i could solve it :) `Context appContext = (Context) TiApplication.getInstance();
  
   TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      String operatorName = tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
   return operatorName;`

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
Context ctx = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```